# Before "the range of", which preposition should come, "within" or "between"?

Tags: prepositions

I have a question about the preposition that can come before the phrase "the range of".

There is a floor wiper with an adjustable handle that can be as short as 18 inches and as long as 35 inches. When you are describing this floor wiper to someone, which sentence can you use?

> The handle length can be adjusted **within** the range of 18-35
> inches.
>
> The handle length can be adjusted **between** the range of 18-35
> inches.

I found both "within the range of ..." and "between the range of ..." on the Internet, but I am not sure which can be used to describe length like this.

Comment: "Between the range of" is much [less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=within+the+range+of%2C+between+the+range+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwithin%20the%20range%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbetween%20the%20range%20of%3B%2Cc0). **Within** is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"between" means "(with)in the space separating two regions, objects, or spaces", but there are many more idiomatic usages of "between".

"I ran between the barns" means you were running from an undefined place to another undefined place, but both of those places were *individually* between the barns.

"I ram from one barn to the other" means exactly what you'd expect.

In your context, "within the range of x to y" means exactly the same thing as "between x and y"; however, I would opt for just using "in", but "within" still works swell, so your first sentence is a-ok.

My general rule for "within" versus "in" is that "in" gets used for definite/certain spaces, whereas "within" gets used for abstract/amorphous spaces. You can also use "within" for definite/certain spaces to emphasize, though. You can very generally just treat "within" as a more abstract version of "in", but of course this is just a basic guideline.

Nonetheless, sometimes "in" to "within" can change the meaning a lot:

> I jumped in the lake. (into)

> I jumped within the lake. (inside of)

Another case, although it is slightly idiomatic:

> True [EMOTION] comes from within.

The "within" here implies a dummy object, like "within you" or "within one". The aforementioned is a great example of the "abstraction" that I mentioned; "in a [HUMAN]" would very commonly be used for things inside of the human's body, whereas "within a human" would very commonly be used for things inside of the human's mind.

Anyways, I believe that the second sentence may be deemed ungrammatical by many people. The second sentence would sound far more natural if it were phrased as it is below:

> The handle length can be adjusted between 18 and 35 inches.

The en dash, "–", had to change to "and", because the en dash reads like "to", and "between" is used like:

> between ... **and** ...

To use "*???* ... **to** ...", you'd have to say "*from* ... **to** ..."

This paradigm for "between ... **and** ..." and "from ... **to** ..." is well-established and very common — [source](https://englishforjournalists.journalism.cuny.edu/2014/12/08/betweenandfromto/).

Here are the super common ways to say what you want to say:

> The handle length can be adjusted within the range of 18 to 35 inches.

> The handle length can be adjusted within the range of 18–35 inches.

> The handle length can be adjusted in the range of 18 to 35 inches.

> The handle length can be adjusted in the range of 18–35 inches.

> The handle length can be adjusted between 18 and 35 inches.

> The handle length can be adjusted from 18 to 35 inches

> The handle length can be adjusted from 18–35 inches.